# How to sync facebook contacts after Ubersync deprecated

Tags: contacts, sync, facebook

As of May 2015, Ubersync no longer works due to a change Facebook made. How can I keep my Android contacts book synced with my Facebook contacts now? I imagine other apps have suffered a similar fate.

Comment: Unlikely that any app fixes that in the future.

http://techcrunch.com/2015/04/28/facebook-api-shut-down/

Answer (score 0):

If you add Facebook IDs to the note field of your contacts (or you have been using a HTC Sense device which had probably done it for you), you can try
[ContactSyncDuck for Facebook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lifeternet.profilephotosync).

Disclaimer: I am affiliated with this application.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Eyecon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eyecon.global) which automatically syncs your contacts with pictures from Facebook (and other social media sources)

Disclaimer: I work for Eyecon